# Why doesn't mySQL allow users@'%' from localhost?

Tags: mysql, localhost

It seems that the solution to accepting users from localhost is to create a copy of the user with @'localhost' (in addition to user@'%').  I'm trying very hard to understand the logic here, because it seems kind of bat-nuts crazy that the 'any host' wildcard, '%', wouldn't also accept localhost connections.  Creating a second user isn't very practical when dealing with a large number of users.  If a user changes their own password, it would then leave the other one unaffected.

Is there any sort of workaround to allowing user@'%' to accept localhost connections?

Answer (score 3):

The `localhost` style of connecting to mysqld forces the mysql client to authenticate via the socket file.

Connecting via the wildcard `%` demands the connecting to mysqld via TCP/IP.

If have `myuser@'%'` with a password of `mys3cr3t`, and you do not want to add `myuser@'localhost'`, I would like to suggest the following:

Connect to mysql like this

```
mysql --protocol=tcp -umyuser -pmys3cr3t
```

Using `--protocol=tcp` forces the mysql client program to use the TCP/IP to connect

Once you connect, run this query

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

[CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

[**I wrote about this in the DBA StackExchange back on Jan 18, 2012**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897).

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the anonymous users, as [MySQL's pattern matching will match them first](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36576).

Run the `mysql_secure_installation` script or [remove them manually](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html#id445872).